# UIScrollView : scrolling offset w.r.t page size

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

Am working on an iPhone App that displays photos in a UIScrollView (like the in-built Photos App) ; Earlier (i.e. when I started coding), I added the photos one 'immediately' next to the other ; i.e. each photo size is the screen width size (for example, 640px for iPhone Retina) ; so, the first photo's X-axis point starts at 0.0 ; for the 2nd, it starts at 640.0, for the third, at 980.0 and so on. Recently, I decided to add a black spacing between the photos like this (this is the black spacing between two photos):

[image]

Now, sya, the black spacing is for 40px. So, the first photo's offset (i.e. x-axis offset) is at 0.0 ; for the 2nd photo, it is at 360px (i.e. 320px is the width of 1st photo + 40px of black spacing). But the problem here is this : By default, the scroll view seems to take the photo width as the 'default' scroll offset ; i.e. if I am at the 1st photo & then scroll right, then it scrolls to 320.0px offset by 'default' (I get this value in scrollViewDidEndDecelerating), though I want it to scroll to 360px (adding the 40px of black spacing). How do I change this default scroll offset?

Answer (score 0):

This may be happening because of your second view in scroll view starts with that extra 40px what you can do is inspite of adding that extra 40px black strip to the beginning of next view add it to the end of everyview something like bellow

```
 for( int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{

UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame : CGRectMake (incX,0,your_Scroll.frame.size.width,your_Scroll.frame.size.height)];
    myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, myView.frame.size.width - 40, myView.frame.size.height)];

    imgView.backgroundColor =   [UIColor clearColor];

    imgView.image   =   [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Image%i.png",i]];

    [myView addSubview:imgView]

    [your_Scroll addSubview:myView];

    incX+= 320;
}
```

Hope this will help you :).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion ; The point is am not adding any UIView to get that black spacing ; all I'm doing is adding the photos to UIScrollView with a spacing of 40px between them ; so, in effect by default the space between them gets shown as black. That is, for example, am adding the 1st photo at offset 0.0px to UIScrollView (all photos are of width 320.0px) ; then am adding the 2nd photo at 360px (320px (width of 1st photo) + 40px (for the black spacing)) and so on. In effect, the gaps (in the scroll view) between the photos get filled with black.

Comment: @Jean how can I help you. Tell me I'll do what I can. May be you should first try my logic above.